# Is it possible to delete an image from google search results without approval of site owner?

Tags: magento2, product-images, search

We have a Magento site with lots of images. Since we have competitors, there is a possibility to delete the images from the search engines like google image search.

In this case, I want to know that, is it possible to delete an image from google image search without the approval of website owner?

I have read many posts about it but not have a satisfied answer. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove someone else's website image if it is covered in [Google Removal Policies](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2744324) Other wise you cannot ask google to remove someone else's website image.

Reference:
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4628134?hl=en

Comment: You are welcome :)